# I want to get a specific line in a text file to appear in a text box

Tags: c#

I have a .txt file that has data in it on multiple likes, for example:

```
Line 1 has - Name: Tom

Line 2 has - Score 1: 10

Line 3 has - Score 2: 5

Line 4 has - Score 3: 5

Line 5 has - Score 4: 7

Line 6 has - Score 5: 10

Line 7 has - Total Score: 37

Line 8 has - Name: Ben

Line 9 has - Score 1: 5

Line 10 has - Score 2: 10

Line 11 has - Score 3: 10

Line 12 has - Score 4: 0

Line 13 has - Score 5: 5

Line 14 has - Total Score: 30
```

What I am trying to do is select the **line 1**, (`Name: Tom`) and **line 7** (`Total Score: 37`) and **line 8** and **line 14** from the .txt file. Is there any way I can select these specific lines in the .txt file so that I can display them in a text box?

The result I want is to be able to put the chosen lines into a text box. Any help/Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Personally, I would just loop through using the `StreamReader` and do a check to see if the current line being read .Contains "Name" or "Total" and store them until you reach the end of the stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a class to store the name and the score. This allows you to fill a list with score information.

```
    class Player
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Score { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Name,-15}: {Score,4}";
        }
    }
```

You can enumerate the lines and look if a line starts with specific strings.

```
const string path = @"C:\Users\Me\Documents\TheFile.txt";

var players = new List<Player>();
Player currentPlayer = null;
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(path)) {
    if (line.StartsWith("Name:")) {
        // We have a new person. Create a `Player` object and add it to the list.
        currentPlayer = new Player { Name = line.Substring(6) };
        players.Add(currentPlayer);
    } else if (line.StartsWith("Total Score:") &&
        Int32.TryParse(line.Substring(13), out int score)) {

        // We have a score number. Convert it to `int` and assign it to the current player.
        currentPlayer.Score = score;
    }
}
```

Note that `Player` is a reference type and that therefore `currentPlayer` references the same player object already in the list. This means that `currentPlayer.Score = score;` also changes the score of the player in the list.

If you override the `ToString` method of the `Player` class, this enables you to add players to a `ListBox`. The listbox will then automatically use `ToString` to display them. This is more flexible than textboxes, because you always need only one listbox, no matter how many players you have.

```
listBox1.DataSouce = players; // Displays all the players with their scores.
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse data into classes.  The you can get names and scores :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string line = "";
            Player newPlayer = null;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    string[] splitLine = line.Split(new char[] { ':' }).ToArray();

                    if (line.StartsWith("Name"))
                    {
                        newPlayer = new Player();
                        Player.players.Add(newPlayer);

                        newPlayer.name = splitLine[1].Trim();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (line.StartsWith("Score"))
                        {
                            if (newPlayer.scores == null) newPlayer.scores = new List<int>();
                            newPlayer.scores.Add(int.Parse(splitLine[1]));

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            string[] playersNames = Player.players.Select(x => x.name).ToArray();

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" , ", playersNames));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class Player
    {
        public static List<Player> players = new List<Player>();

        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<int> scores { get; set; }

    }
}
```